# NodeJs - How to handle database request and improve efficiency

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

Now I write a data visualization web, so I use ansyc library to query data and then send to client.
Everything works well except not real async.
The previous request will block the server. 
Here is my seudo code.

```
var express = require('express');
var dbrequest = require('../dbconnection');
var async = require('async');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    async.parallel([
        dbrequest.func1,
        dbrequest.func2,
        dbrequest.func3,
    ],function(err, results){
    res.render('appDetail', { 
        ans1:results[0],
        ans2:results[1],
        ans1:results[2]
    })
}
```

My DB is Mysql.
The answer is right but I want to increase efficiency.
Does DB hit the bottleneck?
Could you give me some advise to improve it?
================================(update)=================================
Thanks for comments.
I updated my question.
So my problem now is how to improve the data request efficiency?
My dbconnection code
Here is my dbconnection.js code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var async = require('async');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host :
    user :
    password :
    database :
});
exports.func1 = function(callback){
    //all function read data only.
    connection.query('mysql', function(err, rows, fields){
        callback(null,rows);
    })
}
```

Comment: You cannot do async just like that if one query depend to another

Comment: If there are two users , user1 send request for data and then user2 request only for static page. Why would user1's request block the server?

Comment: How about Facebook, Twitter handle data request problem? Could you give me some advise? thanks.

Comment: There is no blocking going on here. You're executing three functions in parallel and your callback gets called when all three have completed. Now if `dbrequest.func*()` are blocking, that's another story, but the code you've currently posted is not blocking in itself.

Comment: Thanks  @mscdex. So if dbrequest.func*() are blocking, how can I do?

Comment: @鄭元傑 It depends. What do those functions *actually* do? Do they read synchronously from disk? Do they calculate PI? Something else?

Comment: I updated my dbconnection.js. Plz have a look. Thanks~

Comment: The idea is that if the query 1 write and the query 2 read. The query 2 is going to complete the execution before query 1 competition

Comment: at this point you have to run the functions in sync then render

Comment: All the db functions only read data from DB.  
According to [Async Lib](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel)
parallel(tasks, [callback])
Run the tasks array of functions in parallel, without waiting until the previous function has completed.  

My curiosity is why user1 request would block user2.  
In my remember, NodeJs run async. Although user1 is blocked by its own db request, NodeJs can respond to user2,can't it?

Comment: Use promises I think so you can grab data from a query and chain it? https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/929  See second post

Comment: so Async lib is not really async ? I am much more confused about async and promise. How to tell real async function? OTZ

Comment: There's a lot of bad advice here, too bad we can't downvote comments.  There's nothing wrong with the code as you have it.  Moving to promises won't magically make that specific code more efficient.  Your key to efficiency will be in making the database operations faster and more efficient since that's where your bottleneck will be.  There are entire areas of study on how to do that and, in the end, it's very specific to your database and your data and your configuration and also has to do with what an be cached and what cannot.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for your comment. I will try to optimize my SQL. :)

Comment: @jfriend00 My friend found out the problem..... The reason why user1 would block user2 is all routing use the same async. Node Js could handle multi request but all request would stuck in the async parallel process.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer...
[Nodejs mysql lib](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pool-options)
The bottleneck is stock on connection.
Every request should create a new db connection.
I use pool to solve the problem.